# How can I format labels and buttons in Python Tkinter, for example changing the colour, font and size of the text and the background for buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code, I create a button and want it to be font Roboto, size 28 and the colour red. How can I do this?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
foo = Button(root, text="foo", command=lambda: print("bar"))
foo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use the `font` and `fg` options for the text and `bg` option for the button background of `Button` widget.

Comment: You should be able to get an answer to this question by reading available documentation. Please do some research, then show us what you've tried if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

# set the font
f = font.Font(size=28)

# create button
foo = Button(root, text='foo!', bg='red', fg='white',command=lambda: print("bar"))
# apply font to button label
foo['font'] = f
# add button to window
foo.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]